# Issue with Bang opeartions in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, activerecord

I have enum like
status[opened ,closed] of model Course

```
@course = Course.find(1)
@course.opened! 
this method which is provided by rails which causes an issue
```

but when I worked with local enviorment it works perfectly it updates the value.
but when I worked on QA envoirment which is deployed on aws it sometimes not updating course status to opened which remains in closed.`your text`

Comment: Maybe you want to share your Course-Model and some logs?

Comment: But sometimes it works? Obviously this isn't an issue "with bang operations" and certainly tagging with aws is silly.